# @insert_name doesn't always work

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

In the comments sections of questions I often try to write "@whoever" before commenting. Sometimes it works fine; other times the entire "@_" statement is omitted from the comment when it is published.

Why is this? Am I doing something wrong (some of the time)? Can it be fixed?

Comment: If you're mentioning the person who owns the post and no one else has commented, then it is automatically stripped away. There are other minor silly logics involved, which I'm not going to summarize here... read this instead: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020

Comment: @rm-rf Awesome, thanks for clearing this up!